# Remove Special character using php?

Tags: php

I have proble with string

```
 $string = 'United KingdomÂ Â ,ArgentinaÂ Â ';
```

I want to remove " Â Â ".

Can anybody tell how to remove and make string showing above like

```
$string = 'United Kingdom ,Argentina';
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for giving your valuable time i have found its solution with (html_entity_decode()) this function

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Regex` by `Preg Replace` it as like

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $string);
```

Or if you want only replace the character `Â` then you can do like

```
$string = str_replace('Â', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple.. Try this:

```
$string = str_replace('Â', ' ', $string);
```